# Font Replacement for Search Input Placeholders

Tags: cufon, font-replacement

All-One-Cufon currently, will to change to other ttf font replacement..

When using the All-One-Cufon plugin I am find that the cufon code can't replace the placeholder with the same html5 code that would normal be used to change color:

```
#rightHalf input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #f9a11b;
}
#rightHalf input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #f9a11b;
}
#rightHalf input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #f9a11b;
}
```

Cufon Code:

```
Cufon.replace('#rightHalf input::-webkit-input-placeholder');
Cufon.replace('#rightHalf input:-moz-placeholder');
Cufon.replace('#rightHalf input:-ms-input-placeholder');
```

This did not work. Neither did attempting to target the input:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search for Products, Services & Supplier ">
```

Cufon Code:

```
Cufon.replace('#s');
```

Resulting In:

```
    <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search for Products, Services &amp; Supplier ">    
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 3px; height: 12px; ">
<canvas width="15" height="14" style="width: 15px; height: 14px; top: -1px; left: -2px; "></canvas><cufontext></cufontext></cufon>
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search"></form>
```

Failure and messes up spacing...

CSS (fontFamily on cufon JS set to "arialnarrow"):

```
font-family: 'arialnarrow';
```

and

```
font: arialnarrow;
```

and

```
font-family: 'arialnarrow' !important;
```

and

```
font: arialnarrow !important;
```

did nothing... as I anticipated, seeing as the cufon adds html to change the texts appearance and the placeholder is within an input, targetable by css and not html..

- Does anyone know how I could do this?? **Font replacement for placeholders from ttf fonts??**
- **Arial Narrow** for **[Gonzit.com](http://gonzit.com/)** <-- top search bar placeholder text needs to be replaced..
- **Any help is appreciated, need to close ASAP!!**

Ted

Comment: `font-family: 'Arial Narrow';` is what you are looking for